# How to mock Eloquent Model in Laravel 8 when calling a route in PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to mock a method in the Model so that I am able to test the controller api endpoint with different scenarios.

I am currently using Laravel 8 with PhpUnit and Mockery package.
In the route I am using Route model binding.

**api.php**

```
Route::get('/api/{project}', [ProjectController::class, 'show']);
```

**ProjectController.php**

```
class ProjectController extends Controller 
{
    public function show(Project $project)
    {
        $state = $project->getState();
        
        return response()->json($state);
    }
}
```

**ProjectControllerTest.php**

```
class ProjectControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     * @group ProjectController
     */
    public function shouldReturn200ForValidProjectGuid()
    {
        $project = Project::factory()->create();

        $mock = Mockery::mock(Project::class);

        // I have also tried this, see error below
        // $mock = Mockery::mock(Project::class)->makePartial();

        $this->app->instance(Project::class, $mock);

        $mock->shouldReceive('getState')->andReturn('New South Wales');

        $response = $this->getJson("/api/{$project->guid}");
        
        $response->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJson([
                'data' => 'New South Wales'
            ]);
     }
}
```

I am currently getting this error

```
Received Mockery_0_App_Models_Project::resolveRouteBinding(), but no expectations were specified Exception caught at [/usr/src/app/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Loader/EvalLoader.php(34) : eval()'d code@924
```

I have tried other options like makePartial() instead, however it results in the following error as well

```
Received Mockery_0_App_Models_Project::__construct(), but no expectations were specified Exception caught at [/usr/src/app/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Loader/EvalLoader.php(34) : eval()'d code@924
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Why not use standart mock phpunit $stub = $this->createMock(SomeClass::class) ?

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков I tried using it but it still doesn't work, would you be able to please provide an example

Comment: I read the error message that `resolveRouteBinding` method is called on the mock, but the mock does not know what to do with the call and therefore throws an exception. What could help is to actually specify this missing expectation before letting the system use the mock.

Comment: @hakre would you be able to please provide an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following. I have changed the controller response slightly to make it work with `assertJson()`.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/projects/{project}', [ProjectController::class, 'show']);
```

**ProjectController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Project;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Project $project)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'state' => $project->getState()
        ]);
    }
}
```

**ProjectControllerTest**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\Project;
use Mockery;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ProjectControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_example()
    {   
        $mock = Mockery::mock(Project::class)->makePartial();

        $mock->shouldReceive('resolveRouteBinding')->andReturnSelf();
        $mock->shouldReceive('getState')->andReturn('NSW');

        $this->app->instance(Project::class, $mock);

        $response = $this->get('/projects/1');

        $response->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJson([
                'state' => 'NSW'
            ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid answer as you not mock a model... But whatever...

Answer (score -1):

You don't mock models, you are already using a `Factory` so you still use that to create "mock" data on your model.

```php
$project = Project::factory()->create(['state' => 'New South Wales']);
```

Read more about factories and unit testing in Laravel. See the official documentation.

Comment: State is not part of the project model, this is an external db called in the model, I only want to mock the method to return something different. Otherwise I would have used factory instead

Comment: Okay, so you still do not mock a Model, you mock what is inside the model, can you show the model code ?